# Position of the entities in the sonata dashboard

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I would like to know how to make sure that the element of my dashboard is on the right side as in the following image:

[image]

At the code level, I entered my entities in the services.yml file as in the tutorial. On the other hand I do not know how to recover my entity in the file config.yml.

For now in the file confi.yml I have this:

```
dashboard:
    blocks:

        // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
        -
            position: left
            type: sonata.admin.block.admin_list
```

I thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is necessary that in your config you do this:

```
-
            position: left
            type: sonata.admin.block.admin_list
            settings:
                groups: [sonata_page1]
        -
            position: right
            type: sonata.admin.block.admin_list
            settings:
                groups: [sonata_page2]
    groups:
        sonata_page1:
            items:
                - admin.benevole

        sonata_page2:
            items:
                - admin.patient
```

Look at this link: [Here](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/dashboard.html)